# gcloud: how to get ip addresses of group of managed instances

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

My problem is to create 5k instances and retrieve there public IP addresses.

Specifically for zone us-west1-a I can create a group of 50 instances by the following:

`gcloud compute instance-groups managed create test --base-instance-name morning --size 50 --template benchmark-template-micro --zone us-west1-a`

Questions:

1. How to specify the start-script to run each created instances? I can't find them [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-groups/managed/create).
2. How to get the public IP addresses of those created instances?

Answer (score 0):

the `startup-script` can be assigned to the template for the `instance` used; see [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create).

one can obtain information with `gcloud compute instance-groups managed` [describe](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-groups/managed/describe).

while there are no `public` IP addresses unless you'd assign `external` IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Martin, the startup-script is configured in the instance template.

Unfortunately, there is no API that lists the ip addresses of the instances in the group. There are however APIs (and gcloud commands) to get the list of instances and the ip addresses of instances. Here is an example to fetch this information from the command line:

```
gcloud compute instance-groups list-instances $INSTANCE_GROUP --uri \
    | xargs -I '{}' gcloud compute instances describe '{}' \
        --flatten networkInterfaces[].accessConfigs[] \
        --format 'csv[no-heading](name,networkInterfaces.accessConfigs.natIP)'
```

To speed this up, you may want to use xarg's `-P` flag to parallelize the instance describe requests.

Since all instances in the group have the same prefix. You can also just do a list search by prefix. Although, this may pull in another that uses the same prefix even if not part of the instance group:

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter='name ~ ${PREFIX}*' \
    --flatten networkInterfaces[].accessConfigs[] \
    --format 'csv[no-heading](name,networkInterfaces.accessConfigs.natIP)'
```